# The statistical average of a continuous value: $\overline{O} = \int O(x) \rho(x) dx$, but coordinate invariant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, lagrange-multiplier, entropy

I am trying to solve a Lagrange multiplier problem for the following equation

$$
L= - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho(x) \ln \frac{\rho(x)}{q(x)} dx + \alpha \left( 1- \int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho(x) dx \right) +\beta \left( \overline{O} - \int_{-\infty}^\infty  O(x) \rho(x)  dx \right) \tag{1}
$$

for $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \rho(w)} =0$.

Where the first term is the relative entropy, the second term is the constraint that it sums to one, and the last term is the constraint of an observable involving its average value. The problem solves for the probability measure that maximizes the relative entropy of a continuous parametrization x.

Eventually, I wish to apply the probability measure to a curved manifold. This is why coordinate invariance is very interesting to me.

---

An interesting property of the relative entropy is that its equations remains invariant with respect to a change in variable. Indeed,

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho(x)\ln \frac{\rho(x)}{q(x)} dx \to  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho(y(x)) \left|\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right|\ln \frac{\rho(y(x))\left|\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right|}{q(y(x)) \left|\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right|} dx  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho(y)\ln \frac{\rho(y)}{q(y)} dy \tag{2}
$$

and

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho(x)dx \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho(y(x)) \left|\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right| dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \rho(y) dy \tag{3}
$$

---

However, the last term isn't. Indeed:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty O(x) \rho (x)  dx \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty O(y(x)) \left|\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right|  \rho (y(x))  \left|\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right| dx =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty   O(y) \rho (y(x)) \left|\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right| dy  \tag{4}
$$

---

How can I modify the integral that contains O so that it is coordinate invariant?

What is the expression for the average of a function O(x) over a continuous parametrization x, such that the average value is coordinate invariant?

---

edit:

It appears to me that the solution is to consider the observable to be the ratio between two quantities:

$$
\overline{O} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{A(x)}{B(x)} \rho(x) dx
$$

where $O(x) := A(x)/B(x)$. In this case, it is invariant for the same reason that equation (2) is:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{A(x)}{B(x)} \rho(x) dx \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{A(y(x))  \left| \frac{dy}{dx} \right| }{B(y(x))  \left| \frac{dy}{dx} \right|} \rho(y(x)) \left| \frac{dy}{dx} \right| dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{A(y) }{B(y) } \rho(y)  dy
$$

Can anyone weight in?

Comment: crossposted: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/754961/the-average-of-a-continuous-value-overlineo-int-ox-rhox-dx-but-co

Comment: Is that feasible? Does the standard mean, for example, have that property?

Comment: @Aruralreader  There has to be a way; for instance, the average height of snow in a given area does not depend on the coordinate system.

Comment: @Aruralreader The differential entropy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy doesn't have the property of coordinate invariance. But the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence is the modification that cures it. There has to be a modification that cures it to for the observables.

Comment: The average depth, correct, the average height, no.

Comment: So maybe $O(x) - O(x_0)$ rather than $O(x)$?

Comment: @Aruralreader Will I see $\int \frac{O(x)}{A(x)} \rho(x) dx$, $\int O(x) \frac{\rho(x)}{q(x)} dx$ and your suggestion of $\int \left( O(x) - O(x_0) \right) \rho(x) dx$. Any argument why I should pick one over the other?

Comment: @Aruralreader Actually, I don't think your suggestion works, because it will not cancel the |dy/dx| term. The suggestion $\int O(x)\rho(x)/q(x) dx$ doesn't work either, because it assigns $\rho(x)/q(x)$ instead of $\rho(x)$ to the probability of the observable. Leaving only the suggestion $\int O(x)/A(x) \rho(x) dx$.